# Custom Route Type in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've got a custom route type:

```
class MyRoute implements Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\RouteInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

How do I register it with `Zend\Mvc\Router\RoutePluginManager`? I can't figure out which config key it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config key you're looking for is `route_manager`.

For reference, there's a handy table in the manual which maps managers, interfaces, method names and configuration keys -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#configuration-mapping-table

Comment: Thanks! I also hadn't implemented the static `factory()` method yet. I think I tried the `route_manager` key already but thought it was wrong when I still got an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Another place you can check is in the class [Zend\Mvc\Service\ModuleManagerFactory](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Service/ModuleManagerFactory.php#L88) inside the [zendframework/zend-mvc](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc) library.

This class instantiates the default module listeners.

Comment: Thanks! I've looked at all those classes for about an hour and I just can't figure it out.